# Saving and loading different profiles in App.config

Tags: c#, .net

I have an App.config file to remember the user selection for the next time they open the program, which looks like

```
<appSettings>
<add key="key1" value=""/>
<add key="key2" value=""/>
</appSettings>
```

What I would like to do is to allow users to save and load different profiles using those same keys from appSettings, like this

```
<appSettings>
<profile1>
<add key="key1" value="a"/>
<add key="key2" value="a"/>
</profile1>
<profile2>
<add key="key1" value="b"/>
<add key="key2" value="b"/>
</profile2>
</appSettings>
```

but I'm a little unclear on how to do this using App.config. Is App.config even the right place to do this? It seems like that's where I configure what the keys are so multiple versions of keys don't make sense, but on the other hand this works perfectly for one profile and I like being able to do this to get or set values

```
var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
var setting1 = appSettings["key1"];
```

Thanks

Comment: Sadly, no. AppSettings is a key/value repository, which is a bit too simplistic for complex objects such as yours.
SQL or MongoDB structures should be more effective in storing/retrieving these data.
This is a consideration valid only on .NET Framework-based applications. On .NET Core, where `json` config files are used, these data could be properly stored.

Comment: Oh I see thanks, I'm actually using .Net Core so I think I could switch to json config files